# How to add a character like # to the begining of the 1st nonblank line for several files?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a bunch of files, which I would like to use # to comment the 1st non-blank line, the files are not in good format, so there may be 1 or multiple blank lines before the line I want to comment. Any way I can do it? thanks!

As an example:

File1:

```
<blank Line>
this is line 1, and I want to comment.
This is line 2...
```

File2:

```
<blank line>
<blank line>
This is line 1, and I want to comment.
This is line 2...
```

Hope I have state the questions clearly. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -e '\n  \nfoo\nbar' | awk '!p && /[^[:blank:]]/ {$0 = "#" $0; p=1} 1'
```

```
<empty>
<space><space>      
#foo
bar
```

when "p" == 0 and a line with a non-space character appears, add a hash and set p=1. Print every line.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed as OP required.

```
sed ':loop;$!{N; b loop};s/^[ \t\n]*/&#/' file
```

Test file

```
<empty>
<space><space>    
<tab><tab>  
foo
bar
```

result

```
<empty>
<space><space>    
<tab><tab>  
#foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^\s*$/,/\S/{/\S/s/^/#/}' file1 file2 file....
```